# MySQL: Statement with 'LIKE' order by degree of resemblance

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a simple MySQL query that runs on a large set of keywords for the purpose of searching by keyword.

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%keyword%'
```

How can I order the resultant set by degree of resemblance (in this case the string length) with the search keyword of `inter`? For example, the resultant set is something like this.

```
international
internal
internet
interval
intern
internee
internship
```

Is it possible with SQL alone or do I need to do it on the programming level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the data by the string length using `order by length(column_name) desc`:

```
SELECT * 
from table_name 
WHERE column_name LIKE '%inter%'
order by length(column_name) desc
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8de4/1). I chose descending order but you can remove the `desc` to order by ascending length.